# Вывести миллисекунды jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выводить миллисекунды вместе с секундами?

вот мой таймер

```
let waitTimeShow = $('#waitTimeShow');
    let mutShow = $('#mutShow');

    let timerTime = 5;
    waitTimeShow.html(timerTime + "s");
    function timer(){
        timerTime--;
        waitTimeShow.html(timerTime + "s");
        if (timerTime == 0){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate)
            waitTimeShow.addClass('hide');
            mutShow.removeClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){},1000);
        } else {
            setTimeout(timer,1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(timer,1000);
```

Comment: Уточните какие миллисекунды вы хотите выводить. Если речь о unix timestamp, то new Date().getTime()

Comment: есть let timerTime = 5; и при уменьшении этой переменной выводить обратный отсчет миллисекунд для текущей секунды

Comment: setTimeout(timer,1000) - ваш таймер срабатывает раз в секунду, поэтому миллисекунды вывести не получится. Как вариант поменяйте timerTime = 5000; и setTimeout(timer,1); Теперь вы получили миллисекунды. Получить из них целые секунды можно делением на 1000, собственно.

Comment: ничего не понял)

Comment: если делать так waitTimeShow.html((timerTime / 1000) + "s"); то выдает 4876

Comment: По вашему ответу вижу что разобрались :)

Comment: да, спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 2):

ответ на мой вопрос

```
let timerTime = 5000;
    waitTimeShow.html((timerTime / 1000).toFixed(2) + "s");
    function timer(){
        timerTime--;
        waitTimeShow.html((timerTime / 1000).toFixed(2)+ "s");
        if (timerTime === 0){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            waitTimeShow.addClass('hide');
            mutShow.removeClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){},1);
        } else {
            setTimeout(timer,1);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(timer,1);
```